# Oracle Advanced Queues - Dequeueing Commit/Rollback

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, transactions, advanced-queuing

We're attempting to use Oracle AQ to build a queueing system for our app in .NET 4.7.

Basically, our problem is that we would like to wrap the dequeueing process in an upper level transaction containing other instructions and to be able to Commit or Rollback "manually" after executing the queue.Dequeue() instruction.

So far, this only works with Enqueueing:

```
using (var tr = con.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        enqMsg.SenderId = new OracleAQAgent("SUBSCRIBER1");
        enqMsg.Payload = new OracleXmlType(con, new XDocument(
            new XElement("workflowexecution",
                new XElement("id", i),
                new XElement("workflowname", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8)),
                new XElement("requestsource", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 6)))).ToString());

        queue.Enqueue(enqMsg);

        //Other instructions here...

        tr.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        tr.Rollback();
    }
}
```

With the same approach, we are trying to perform a

```
queue.Dequeue()
```

and then Commit or Rollback, but that doesn't seem to work. Here's the Dequeueing snippet:

```
//Queue declaration
queue = new OracleAQQueue("QueueName", con)
{
    MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Xml,
    NotificationConsumers = new[] { "SUBSCRIBER1" },
    DequeueOptions =
    {
        ConsumerName = "SUBSCRIBER1",
        DequeueMode = OracleAQDequeueMode.Remove,
        Visibility = OracleAQVisibilityMode.OnCommit,
    }
};

//Dequeueing process
using (var tr = con.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        OracleAQMessage _deqMsg = queue.Dequeue();

        //read the payload 
        var reader = _deqMsg?.Payload as XmlTextReader;

        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("Received message from queue: " + reader.ReadOuterXml());
        }                     

        //Further instructions...
        tr.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tr.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Dequeueing always commits the transaction and removes the messages permanently from the queue, even when executing Rollback instead of Commit. Anyone has a clue why it is not working with Dequeueing?

Comment: Define "not working". Also, consider not using exception handlers that simply throw away any error without an opportunity for inspection.

Comment: By not working, I mean that the message is permanently deleted from the queue after Dequeueing, even after performing a Rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Set the dequeue options after the transaction had begun or pass it to the `queue.Dequeue()`

Answer (score 0):

Oracle queue has an attribute which is
`max_retries`. Once this number is reached, if the transactions are rolled back, the message will be removed from the queue and added to an exception queue.
I read somewhere on the internet that by default this value is 5 and I confirmed that while testing a queue that I created (Oracle Database 11.2.0.1.0 SE). Therefore, by default, it seems that after 5 attempts to dequeue, the message will be removed from the normal queue and added to its exception queue. This is the definition of attribute max_retries from an oracle manual.

> Limits the number of times a dequeue with the REMOVE mode can be attempted on a message. The maximum value of max_retries is 2**31 -1.

> A message is moved to an exception queue if RETRY_COUNT is greater than MAX_RETRIES. RETRY_COUNT is incremented when the application issues a rollback after executing the dequeue. If a dequeue transaction fails because the server process dies (including ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION) or SHUTDOWN ABORT on the instance, then RETRY_COUNT is not incremented.

> Note that max_retries is supported for all single consumer queues and 8.1-compatible or higher multiconsumer queues but not for 8.0-compatible multiconsumer queues.

Source: `https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_aqadm.htm#ARPLS109`